# NameError: name 'example_batch_predictions' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was running a code and I received this error. The code is below.

```
for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1): 
example_batch_predictions = model(input_example_batch)
print(example_batch_predictions.shape,"(BATCH_SIZE, sequence_length,vocab_size)")

model.summary()

sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions,num_samples=1)
sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()
```

and the error i recieved is

> NameError Traceback (most recent call last) ipython-input-45-f7c2773af286> in module()
> sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions, num_samples=1)
> sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()
>
> NameError: name 'example_batch_predictions' is not defined

Comment: First of all, I think your copied code has an indent problem, I suggest if you can correct it with a short edit.  Second, is print(example_batch_predictions....) being executed? and you are seeing the print in your stdin? I was thinking maybe the code never goes inside the loop, so you never define "example_batch_predictions"